# Is there an easier way to iterate through a list of objects properties in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, properties, eloquent

I have a Laravel app where I am using a bit of code which feels really unintuitive.

In the code I return a list of objects (`$occupied`) which all have the the column 'property'. I then go on to create an array of the list of objects 'property's (`$occupiedproperty`) just to use it in a whereNotIn call.

```
    if ($occupied = Residency::currentResidents()){

        // Here is the pointless part //////
        $occupiedproperty = array();
        foreach ($occupied as $occ) {
            array_push($occupiedproperty, $occ->property);
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////

        return Property::whereNotIn('id', $occupiedproperty)->get();
    }
```

This code works fine to do the job but creating a new array when I already have a list of objects seems lazy. I tried looking at eloquent's documentation but I couldn't figure this out.

I need to be able to access the 'property' column of `$occupied` so I can run something like `whereNotIn('id', $occupied->property)`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't test it right now, but this should work (it should work even without casting to array the `$occupied` collection):

```
$occupiedProperties = array_pluck((array)$occupied, 'property');
```

It uses the `array_pluck()` helper method: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#arrays